# How can you sort an array in Ruby starting at a specific letter, say letter f?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a text array.

```
text_array = ["bob", "alice", "dave", "carol", "frank", "eve", "jordan", "isaac", "harry", "george"]
```

`text_array = text_array.sort` would give us a sorted array.

However, I want a sorted array with f as the first letter for our order, and e as the last.

So the end result should be...

```
text_array = ["frank", "george", "harry", "isaac", "jordan", "alice", "bob", "carol", "dave", "eve"]
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest would be to rotate the sorted array:

```
text_array.rotate(offset) if offset = text_array.find_index { |e| e.size > 0 and e[0] == 'f' }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `["ab","af"]` sorted be `["af", "ab"]`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don’t know. Should it?

Comment: Chris, do you want to sort on letters after the first when the first letter of two words is the same?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
result = (text_array.select{ |v| v =~ /^[f-z]/ }.sort + text_array.select{ |v| v =~ /^[a-e]/ }.sort).flatten
```

It's not the prettiest but it will get the job done.

Edit per comment. Making a more general piece of code:

```
before = []
after = []
text_array.sort.each do |t|
  if t > term
    after << t
  else
    before << t
  end
end
return (after + before).flatten
```

This code assumes that `term` is whatever you want to divide the array. And if an array value equals `term`, it will be at the end.

Comment: Thanks that's great. What if I wanted to get a little more specific. Instead of starting with "f". I want to start with "fad". "fad-z" is first and then "a-fad" is next?

Comment: You could also use `text_array.sort.each do |t|` instead of `text_array.each do |t|` so you don't have to do `before.sort` and `after.sort`

Comment: RE your first solution, if you don't like `flatten`, you could write `sorted_end.concat(sorted_beginning)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using a hash:

```
alpha = ('a'..'z').to_a
  #=> ["a", "b", "c",..."x", "y", "z"] 
reordered = alpha.rotate(5) 
  #=> ["f", "g",..."z", "a",...,"e"] 
h = reordered.zip(alpha).to_h
  # => {"f"=>"a", "g"=>"b",..., "z"=>"u", "a"=>"v",..., e"=>"z"}

text_array.sort_by { |w| w.gsub(/./,h) }
  #=> ["frank", "george", "harry", "isaac", "jordan",
  #   "alice", "bob", "carol", "dave", "eve"]
```

A variant of this is:

```
a_to_z = alpha.join
  #=> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" 
f_to_e = reordered.join
  #=> "fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcde"

text_array.sort_by { |w| w.tr(f_to_e, a_to_z) }
  #=> ["frank", "george", "harry", "isaac", "jordan",
  #   "alice", "bob", "carol", "dave", "eve"]
```

Comment: I like the substitution cipher feel of the first solution.

Comment: @MarkThomas, I decided it was better than #2, so deleted the second.

Comment: [`tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/String.html#method-i-tr) accepts character ranges, i.e. `text_array.sort_by { |w| w.tr('f-za-e', 'a-z') }`

Answer (score 1):

Combining Ryan K's answer and my previous answer, this is a one-liner you can use without any regex:

```
text_array = text_array.sort!.select {|x| x.first >= "f"} + text_array.select {|x| x.first < "f"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, it looks like you want to create sorted list with biased predefined patterns.

ie. let's say you want to define specific pattern of text which can completely change the sorting sequence for the array element.

Here is my proposal, you can get better code out of this, but my tired brain got it for now -

```
an_array = ["bob", "alice", "dave", "carol", "frank", "eve", "jordan", "isaac", "harry", "george"]

# Define your patterns with scores so that the sorting result can vary  accordingly
# It's full fledged Regex so you can put any kind of regex you want.
patterns = {
  /^f/ => 100,
  /^e/ => -100,
  /^g/ => 60,
  /^j/ => 40
}

# Sort the array with our preferred sequence
sorted_array = an_array.sort do |left, right|
  # Find score for the left string
  left_score = patterns.find{ |p, s| left.match(p) }
  left_score = left_score ? left_score.last : 0

  # Find the score for the right string
  right_score = patterns.find{ |p, s| right.match(p) }
  right_score = right_score ? right_score.last : 0

  # Create the comparision score to prepare the right order
  # 1 means replace with right and -1 means replace with left
  # and 0 means remain unchanged
  score = if right_score > left_score
    1
  elsif left_score > right_score
    -1
  else
    0
  end

  # For debugging purpose, I added few verbose data
  puts "L#{left_score}, R:#{right_score}: #{left}, #{right} => #{score}"

  score
end

# Original array
puts an_array.join(', ')

# Biased array
puts sorted_array.join(', ')
```